# How to calculate the possibility of every scenario with respect to correlation? (Stochastic Optimization)

Tags: optimization, probability, correlation, stochastic, discretization

Imagine having two variables with three possible outcomes each:

```
d_1 = [1, 2, 3] and probabilities p_1 = [0.5, 0.25, 0.25]
d_1 = [1, 2, 3] and probabilities p_2 = [0.5, 0.25, 0.25]
```

Now i can calculate the probability of every possible permutation like this:

scenario_1: d_1 = 1 and d_2 = 2
p(scenario_1) = 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25

But if d_1 and d_2 are correlated the probability of 0.25 is not correct. Now my question:
How do i correct this probability with respect to the correlation?

For example if corr[d_1, d_2] = 1

I feel like the probability of scenario_1 would have to be much higher.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the kind of [correlation](https://medium.com/@outside2SDs/an-overview-of-correlation-measures-between-categorical-and-continuous-variables-4c7f85610365) definition you are using.

To compute the joint probability of two dependent variables `A` and `B`:

```
P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B given A) = P(B) * P(A given B)
```

Provided the correlations are given, it should be possible to compute the [conditional probabilities](https://machinelearningmastery.com/joint-marginal-and-conditional-probability-for-machine-learning/) `P(A given B)` or `P(B given A)`.